# Delphi Write Registry on Windows Service Application

Tags: delphi, registry, admin-rights

I am working on windows service and i need to write registry HKCU keys on windows service mode but i know is not possible.

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVer\Policies\Explorer\RestrictRun
```

I need to write this key, if i cant do that with windows service, how can i write to this key without admin rights? or is it possible?

Actually i can write this key on HKLM but it doesn't work on this key.

```
procedure CreatePolicy(AppName: string);
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
Begin
  Reg := TRegistry.Create;
  try
    Reg.RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    if Reg.OpenKey
      ('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer', True) then
      Reg.WriteInteger('RestrictRun', 1);
    if Reg.CreateKey('RestrictRun') then
      if Reg.OpenKey('RestrictRun', True) then
        Reg.WriteString(AppName, AppName);
  except
    Reg.CloseKey;
    Reg.Free;
  end;
  Reg.CloseKey;
  Reg.Free;
end
```

My Delphi version is XE7.

Comment: Don't you want to make an installer?

Comment: @Victoria no, i dont need for this.

Comment: Which user account's registry do you want to modify? Do you appreciate that services do not run under the logged in user account?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan actually i want for all users and because of i tryed HKLM root key but doesnt work. My application is remote management tool and only machines important for me. This policies should be include all acccounts on remote computer.

Comment: So you need to iterate over all users and write to. Each one's hive. It sounds like you don't fully understand services, users, sessions etc. I think you need better foundations before you proceed. As an interesting thought experiment, what happens if a new user is created after your code runs?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Deffinatelly you’re right, i am still learning.

Comment: @JamesFranklin that was important information that should have been included in your question to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need admin rights to access *most* sections of a user's `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` hive from an app that is running in that user's own session.  However, non-admin users do  not have write access to `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies` specifically, and its subkeys.  So, you are stuck requiring admin rights to modify policies.

A service can use [`CreateProcessAsUser()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429.aspx) to run a non-service app in a specific user's session, if that user is already logged in.  The service can use [`WTSEnumerateSessions()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsenumeratesessionsw) and [`WTSQuerySessionInformation()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsquerysessioninformationw) to locate the desired user session, and then use [`WTSQueryUserToken()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsqueryusertoken) to get the session's user token that is needed for `CreateProcessAsUser()`.

However, if the service wants to *directly* access a user's `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` hive, and if the service is not running as that user, then the service must impersonate that user first, then it can call [`RegOpenCurrentUser()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regopencurrentuser) to obtain an `HKEY` handle to the user's `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` hive.

Comment: thanks for quick answer. You said  "You do not need admin rights to access a user's HKEY_CURRENT_USER hive from an app running in that user's own session" so, my code is not working for normal application and without admin rights. Maybe i got it all wrong. So service executing before logon and my procedure execute on service start, can i write data to hkcu?

Comment: Your code is problematic to begin with. One, you are not using `TRegistry` correctly. Two, although non-admin users have write access to HKCU, they do not have write access to `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies` and its subkeys. So, you are stuck requiring admin rights.